# Gradient function in LogisitcLoss class

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, mathematics, gradient-boosting-decision-trees, derivation

I am going through a code for XGBoost from scratch and I am referring to this repository [here](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/ML-From-Scratch/blob/master/mlfromscratch/supervised_learning/xgboost.py)

The log-loss function is given by [image]

On differentiating the above function with respect to y_pred (referring to the exact variable under the LogisitcLoss() in the repository above), I am getting my gradient as (y - p). Can anyone help me out, what is the reason behind gradient to be -(y - p)?